# Is it possible to customize the Main method signature in a console application?

Tags: c#

I've got a Visual Studio solution that contains many console application projects. Each of these console applications is expected to return a value from a custom exit code enumeration when exiting the `Main` function.

Right now, the `Main` function signature is just `int Main`. So, when returning a value, from our `enum`, we currently have to case the `enum` value to `int`. We're losing out on a bit of forced static analysis because we can't specify that `Main` needs to have a signature of `CustomEnum Main`.

Is it possible to somehow specify a custom `Main` signature so that we can leverage that compile time code analysis?

Comment: Rayn, Just cast the return value to `customEnum`!!!!

Comment: What @combo_ci said. I am scratching my head here wondering why you can't just cast the value before using it...

Comment: You can. That's what I do. I was hoping to impose compile-time restrictions on the return type from `Main`, though, so we can assist developers in remembering to return the proper enum type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible.

> Main can either have a void or int return type.

Source: [Main() and Command-Line Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/)

Answer (score 3):

Nope.  It must have `void` or `int` as the return type.  You can return an enum cast to an int, however:

```
public enum Spork
{
    A,
    B
}

class Program
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        return (int)Spork.A;
    }
}
```

Nothing stops you from making an adapter for the entry point, though:

```
public enum Spork
{
    A,
    B
}

class Program
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        return (int)Spoooon(args);
    }

    /* 
     * Our 'actual' entry point for static analysis purposes
     */
    static Spork Spoooon(string[] args)
    {
        return Spork.A;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think he means he needs to consume the value **outside** of each console app with the type of the Enumeration. I wonder why he won't just cast it?

Comment: He says in the question that he can, but their static analysis tools don't work properly.   I don't agree with your first sentence and wonder where you got that idea.  In any case, ask *him*, not me.

Comment: I can cast it, and do currently cast it. I was simply wondering if there was a way to impose compile-time restrictions on the return type, from `Main`, so that devs working on this solution continue to remember to use the proper enum as the return value from `Main`.

Comment: You cannot.  The return type from `Main` **must** be `void` or `int`.  The only way around that is to make an adapter.